Using loops to extract data in Python from .csv files
I am still very new to Python. I have extracted some data - tyre sales from a
.csv file in 2023/24 (all numbers are made up). Here, the tyre sales have been summarised by month.
import pandas as pd

Tyre_sales_month = pd.read_csv('link/All_Sales_202324.csv')
results_pivot = pd.pivot_table(
    Tyre_sales_month,
    values=['Tyre_Sales'],
    index=['Month'],
    aggfunc={'Tyre_Sales': 'sum'})
cols = 'Tyre_Sales'
results_pivot = results_pivot[cols]
results_pivot.to_csv('link/Tyre_Sales_202324.csv')

The output in the .csv file looks as follows:
Month        Tyre_Sales
January      $5,000
February     $7,000
March        $6,500
April        $5,500
May          $7,200
June         $8,500
July         $7,500
August       $5,200
September    $7,500
October      $8,500
November     $6,200
December     $7,500

I now need to create a loop for the code to go through the following .csv files:
All_Sales_202021.csv
All_Sales_202122.csv
All_Sales_202223.csv
All_Sales_202324.csv

and extract the Tyre_Sales information for previous years (from 202021 until 202324
inclusive) into the following outputs:
Tyre_Sales_202021.csv
Tyre_Sales_202122.csv
Tyre_Sales_202223.csv
Tyre_Sales_202324.csv

I am still getting my head around loops in Python:
# Years
years = ['202021', '202122', '202223', '202324']
years_data = {}

year_data[year] = pd.read_csv("link/All_Sales_" + year + ".csv")

Not sure how to link the year data with the code below and how to introduce a loop for
the code to go through All_Sales files
results_pivot = pd.pivot_table(
    Tyre_sales_month,
    values=['Tyre_Sales'],
    index=['Month'],
    aggfunc={'Tyre_Sales': 'sum'})
cols = 'Tyre_Sales'
results_pivot = results_pivot[cols]
results_pivot.to_csv("link/Tyre_Sales_" + year + ".csv")

Any guidance or help in this direction would be much appreciated.

for year in years:? Is that all you're looking for? What do you already know about loops? Surely you know the basics already, right? If not, like if you haven't done a Python tutorial yet, do that first, cause Stack Overflow isn't built to teach the basics. If this is homework, please read How to ask and answer homework questions. See also [ask]. BTW, welcome to SO! Start with the [tour].

Thank you for the comment, noted.

This can be achieved by putting the code that processes the csv into a for loop.
import pandas as pd

years = ["202021", "202122", "202223", "202324"]
cols = "Tyre_Sales"
for year in years:
    tyre_sales_month = pd.read_csv("link/All_Sales_"+year+".csv")
    results_pivot = pd.pivot_table(
        tyre_sales_month,
        values=["Tyre_Sales"],
        index=["Month"],
        aggfunc={"Tyre_Sales": "sum"},
    )
    results_pivot = results_pivot[cols]
    results_pivot.to_csv("link/Tyre_Sales_"+year+".csv")

The loop will run once for each item in the years list, with the value of year being the current item in the loop.

As an additional tip, you can insert the year value into the input and output filenames using f-strings. F-strings are a little easier to use than concatenating strings with the plus sign.
In your case, the line:
tyre_sales_month = pd.read_csv("link/All_Sales_"+year+".csv")

can become:
tyre_sales_month = pd.read_csv(f"link/All_Sales_{year}.csv")

and the same for the output file name:
results_pivot.to_csv("link/Tyre_Sales_"+year+".csv") # old line
results_pivot.to_csv(f"link/Tyre_Sales_{year}.csv") # new line

